# Compile of <file_name>.vhd failed with 1 errors

Tags: vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity my_nand_gate is
port ( a: in std_logic;
       b: in std_logic;
       c: out std_logic);
end my_nand_gate;


architecture example of my_nand_gate is

begin

    c <= a nand b;

end example;
```

Above is a simple code that executes a NAND gate. On compilation, it shows the error:

> Compile of <file_name>.vhd failed with 1 errors.

What is the error?

Comment: The compiler should tell you that somewhere.

Comment: You're using Vivado. Vivado makes you jump through hoops to see the actual error. It's a pain (and in things like this, so much worse than the old ISE). Just learn to jump through the hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have saved the file or not. Not saving a file and running it will give the error : "Empty source files" on double-clicking the error message.